# cannot delete nested resource in rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I have two tables, recipy and recipe_ingredients, recipe_ingredients is set up as a nested resource

```
resources :recipies do
 resources :recipe_ingredients
end
```

Recipy_ingredients are shown on my recipy_edit page and I want to also delete them from there. 
My edit view:

```
 <% @recipe_ingredients.each do |ing| %>
  <p> <%= ing.amount %> <%= ing.unit %> <%= ing.ingredient.try(:ing_name) %> </p>
  <p><%= link_to ('<i class="material-icons"> clear </i>').html_safe, recipy_recipe_ingredient_path(ing.recipy, ing),
               method: :delete, data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'} %>
</p>
<% end %>
</div>
```

My def edit from the recipies_controller:

```
def edit
 @recipy = Recipy.find(params[:id])
 @recipe_ingredients = @recipy.recipe_ingredients
end
```

def destroy from the recipe_ingredients controller:

```
def destroy
 @recipe_ingredient = RecipeIngredient.find(params[:id])
 recipy = @recipe_ingredient.recipy
 @recipe_ingredient.destroy
 redirect_to recipy
end
```

when trying to open the edit page I keep getting below error msg:

No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"recipe_ingredients", :id=>nil, :recipy_id=>"160"}, missing required keys: [:id]

and this line is highlighted:

```
  <p><%= link_to ('<i class="material-icons"> clear </i>').html_safe, recipy_recipe_ingredient_path(ing.recipy, ing),
```

Is the route messed up? I thought this would be the correct snytax for nested resources? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks. Let me know fi any additional info is needed!

**EDIT**

After some digging around I figured that if I remove a partial before the link_to in the edit view the code works fine. 
My partial before the code:

## Add new Ingredient

```
    <%= form_with model:[@recipy, @recipy.recipe_ingredients.build]  do |form| %>

      <div class="field">
        <%= form.label :amount %>
        <%= form.text_field :amount %>
      </div>

      <div class="field">
        <%= form.label :unit %>
        <%= form.text_field :unit %>
      </div>

      <div class="field">
        <%= form.select(:ingredient_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Ingredient.all, :id, :ing_name))%>
      </div>

      <div class="actions">
        <%= form.submit "add ingredient", remote: true %>
      </div>

    <% end %>
```

and the def create for the recipe_ingredients:

```
   def create
      @recipy = Recipy.find(params[:recipy_id])
      @recipe_ingredient = @recipy.recipe_ingredients.new(recipe_ingredient_params)

      respond_to do |f|
        if @recipe_ingredient.save
          @recipe_ingredients = @recipy.recipe_ingredients.last
          # f.html
          # f.json
          f.js { render :template => "/recipies/updatingview.js.erb", layout: false}

        end
      end
    end
```

Why would this mess up the delete function? If I remove this partial the delete actually works. And advice?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are using nested forms than u need to declare form in this way for edit and new

```
<%= form_with(model: [recipe_ingredient.recipy, recipe_ingredient], local: true) do |form| %>
```

But partials and forms become tricky. Note the square brackets:

```
<%= form_for [@recipy, @recipe_ingredient] do |f| %>
```

Most important, if you want a URI, you may need something like this:

```
recipy_recipe_ingredient_path(@recipy, @recipe_ingredient)
```

Alternatively:

```
[@recipy, @recipe_ingredient]
```

Comment: I actually did not change my form but changed the order so now I first display the recipy_ingredients with the delete option and below that the form to add new recipy_ingredients. it is working fine although I do not really understand what the issue was in the first place. I use AJAX to submit the form so it might be something with that? Thanks anyway